# How to save counter result number into textview?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to make a simple android studio counter program, with one button and two textviews, when I click the "Count" button, the number will increase automatically (increment), and appear in the first textview. How do I do that after clicking the reset button, the last number that appears can be saved in the second textview?
And so on when we click "Count" and "Reset" again the numbers in the second textview add more

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int counter;

    Button count, reset;
    TextView value, result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        count = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCnt);
        reset  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRst);
        value  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.count);
        result  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

        value.setText("" + counter);

        count.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                counter++;
                value.setText("" + counter);
            }
        });

        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                result.setText(value.getText());
                counter = 0;
                value.setText("" + counter);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this solution not working? What is the problem?

Comment: What I want after clicking the reset button, the last number that appears can be stored in the textview, for example: 8, 5, 7, 9, 8 etc.

Comment: `result.setText("" + counter);` before resetting instead of `result.setText(value.getText());`